# Capybara test doesn't pass with database cleaner, must be run twice without database_cleaner to pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

I am trying to test a dropdown with capybara. It works fine if I don't clean the database. I have to clean the database for other test to function properly.

```
config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end
  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end
  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation, {:except => %w[questions]}
  end
  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end
  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```

If I comment out the database cleaner the test must run atleast twice to pass. I can see it retry and always pass on the second try with the same criteria. Once the database cleaner is put into place the test paramenters change on each iteration so it doesn't get a chance to test it a second time.

```html
 context 'when there are questions and answers in the system' do
        before do
          allow_any_instance_of(Form).to receive(:create_questions)
          question = create(:question)
          people.map do |person|
            create(:answer, question: question, person: person) if [true, false].sample
          end
        end

        it 'should allow filtering by whether a person has answered a specific question', js: true do
          @question = Question.first
          select_from_dropdown @question.text, from: 'question'
          click_on 'Search'
          people.each do |person|
            if person.questions.include? @question
              expect(page).to have_content person.full_name
            else
              expect(page).to_not have_content person.full_name
            end
          end
        end
      end
```

This is the helper method which explores the drop down for capybara

```html
  def select_from_dropdown(item_text, options)
    # find dropdown selector
    dropdown = find_field(options[:from], visible: false).first(:xpath, './/..')
    # click on dropdown
    dropdown.trigger('click')
    # click on menu item
    dropdown.find('.menu .item', text: item_text, visible: false).trigger('click')
  end
```

I have tried `sleep` throughout the `select_from_dropdown` thinking that maybe it wasn't loading fast enough but that is not the problem. Ideally this test should work on the first try, but at the very least it needs to pass with the database cleaner.

Comment: What is the rest of your setup for the test (people, etc)? Also, what's with the mocking (`allow_any_instance_of(Form)....`) in a feature test? (Also using `trigger` is a terrible idea in a test)

Comment: On a secondary note (not causing the current issue) your DatabaseCleaner config isn't correct -- it should really be what is recommended by DatabaseCleaner - https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner/tree/14626296ef31b34f7704593667db1d41d81825ab#rspec-with-capybara-example - otherwise you'll get subtle flaky errors (the append_after vs after is very important and checking for driver type vs the metadata is just safer). I'm also assuming you're using Rails <= 5.0 because DatabaseCleaner is not necessary in most cases in Rails 5.1+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `visit` shown in the test, which means you've visited the page before the questions are created and therefore the info expected is not shown on the page. The data would exist from the first run on the second run if you don't clear the DB which explains why it passes second time around. You should always visit the page after creating the test data.

Additionally as I mentioned in the comments you probably want to fix (remove if using Rails 5.1+) your DatabaseCleaner config and the use of `trigger` is a really bad idea in tests since it can do things a user never could.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I was visiting the page elsewhere in the code but I was doing it before I was creating the information. I appreciate the help!!